# How do I configure a single component instance providing multiple services in Castle.Windsor?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I'd like to configure the Windsor container so that a single, singleton-style instance can provide two or more services through the container.

I've found that using the same type in multiple component declarations (XML-based config) will result in an instance of that type being created to provide each component's service interface, which is not the behaviour I desire.

For example:

```
interface IA { }
interface IB { }
class AB : IA, IB { ... }
```

I want the one instance of AB to provide both the IA and IB services.

The specific reason I want to do this is that my concrete DAO implementation extends multiple interfaces.  On the flip side, I have several worker components which hold a reference to different interfaces. The concrete DAO instance respects this, but the constructors of these seperate worker components want the implementation of their seperate interfaces and I desire Castle.Windsor to pass the same object instance through to these worker containers via the respective service requests.

lol, I think that was clear as mud! :P

Does anyone understand what I mean, and has anyone got any ideas how I can acheive this through the XML configuration fo the components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked out the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483515/how-does-castle-windsor-respond-to-a-class-which-implements-multiple-interfaces) (especially the forum post link) that appears to be what you are looking for. Some of the examples are using the Transient lifecycle but I think it will work with Singleton also.

The main pay-off of the [forum post](http://forum.castleproject.org/viewtopic.php?p=14725&sid=f94e87a29e0f4b3c65c62ccd67a064b7) is:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IEntityIndexController, ISnippetController>()
.ImplementedBy<SnippetController>()
.LifeStyle.Transient);
```

The solution is uses the fluent interface (and a recent trunk build) and it wasn't possible to configure in xml last I saw. However, it [may be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274220/does-castle-windsor-support-forwardedtypes-via-xml-configuration) with a facility.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `Forward` method:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IEntityIndexController>()
.ImplementedBy<SnippetController>()
.Forward (typeof(ISnippetController))
.LifeStyle.Transient);
```

From my experiments and from the documentation:

> register the service types on behalf of this component

i think it shoud do the trick.

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the configuration XML?

Answer (score 0):

You can register an instance of an object (instead of an implementation) to be responsible for different implementations:

```
  var ab = new AB();
  container.Register( Component.For<IA>().Instance( ab) );
  container.Register( Component.For<IB>().Instance( ab) );
```

I believe that should work. However, that requires in code configuration, for apparent reasons.

Comment: The main problem with this is using the "new" operator, which means you don't use autowiring for AB.

Comment: Last line should be something like `container.Register( Component.For<IB>().Instance( ab).Named("IBImplementation") );` or you'll get _ComponentRegistrationException: Component AB could not be registered. There is already a component with that name._

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same answer, and this post is the farthest I could get with google. I found that using

```
Classes.FromThisAssembly().Where(t => t.FullName == "Namespace.Classname").WithServiceAllInterfaces()
```

Seems to do the trick for me.